# Enviar parámetro vía url

Tags: django, django-urls

tengo dos urls, una para listar los proyectos y otra url las fases de los distintos proyectos. Cada uno con sus add, delete y update. éstos dos ultimos funcionan perfectamente con `<a href="/erp/projects/delete/' + row.id`.

¿Cómo podría pasar, ese mismo row.id, vía url para rellenar el combo "proyecto" en la url erp/phases/add?

Answer (score 0):

En la ruta creo que debes indicar el tipo de dato que enviarás por url:

Ejemplo con 2 parámetros, ya que pueden enviar multiples:

```
path('tag=<int:tag_id>/order_by=<str:name>', views.QuestionList.as_view())
```

Para tu ruta concreta quizás sea algo así:

```
path('/erp/projects/delete/tag=<int:row_id>', views.NombreVista.as_view())
```

Saludos!